# Including CSS in .php file

Tags: php, css, include, include-path

I am trying to include a css file to my .php file.

Inside the .php file, I have;

```
<?php
Loads of code..
?>
```

I'm wanting it like this..

```
<?php
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
Loads of code..
?>
```

But obviously that doesn't work. Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is basic knownledge, you should better read some tutorials.

Comment: you should seriously go through some php-tutorial. then you can understand how **naive** the question is. It will be solved from the basic knowledge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `echo`..

```
<?php
echo '<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">';
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php
Loads of code..
?>
```

Comment: Or something like this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Uhhhm... You mean something likes this?

```
<?php
echo '<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">';
Loads of code..
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a simple solution here :
https://navydadon.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/css-in-php-file/
hope it will helps :)

Comment: Add the important part of the link to the answer body here. Otherwise if somehow the link becomes dead, you're answer are no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened for me a long ago. The best way to solve this is by inserting the css files in all of the files you have included to make your main php page.