# I want do style tables, but it doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php, record, styling

I want to create a site, which displays a lot of records from a database. To make it more reader-friendly, I want to use a styling. One record is white background, the next blue, the next hhite again.

So I tried this:

```
<?php while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
PRINT "<tr>";
PRINT "<td>"  .$info['articlenr']. "</td>";
PRINT "<td>"  .$info['stock']. "</td>";
PRINT "</tr>";
PRINT "<tr>";
PRINT "<td bgcolor=#0066FF>"  .$info['articlenr']. "</td>";
PRINT "<td bgcolor=#0066FF>"  .$info['stock']. "</td>";
PRINT "</tr>";
}
?>
```

This works for the view, but the problem is, the blue record is the same as the white, not the next one, it just doubles the record and make it another color.

How can I do this right?

Comment: Have you heard about CSS?

Comment: Yes, but this does not work in PHP or does it? And if it does, how can i use it?

Comment: do some googling before posting a question here. Have a look at this www.w3school.com . Try to learn something yourself instead asking many questions others. You will be more happier when learn yourself without any help others. There are plenty of sites and sample codes available in online.

Comment: @user3101966 it doesn't have to work with PHP. HTML doesn't work with PHP neither, it is all text output as far as PHP is concerned. You can use style tags just as any other thing you output from PHP. Also, you can serve files that are not PHP (such as images and yes css) from your server any day of the week. By the way, the browsers are happy to read a linked file as css even if it has the extension is .php (if you instruct them to do it from your HTML). The only thing to be aware of is to set the right headers (with the function header) for each content type you output (HTML, CSS, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:nth-of-type(even)` to get even/odd combination of color's.

Here is a demo example:

**html:**

```
<table>
<tr><td>item1</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>item2</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>item3</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>item4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**css:**

```
tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #0066FF; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pjqZ/1/)

Comment: you may have a solution to just add this to the <tbody>?

Comment: but it's useless..why you want to add it to <tbody>??

Comment: cuz your solution affects <thead) also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in PHP, you could do it like this :

```
<?php 
$iter = 0;
$color1 = 'red'; //can se hex code too, like #0066FF;
$color2 = 'blue';

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    echo '<tr style="background-color:'.( ($iter%2==0) ? $color1 : $color2).';">';
    // rest of the printing stuff
    $iter++;
}
?>
```

Statement

```
($iter%2==0) ? $color1 : $color2
```

does this : it asks the question whether iterator (or row number) is even. If yes, the it takes color1. If not (row is uneven) it takes the second color.

PHP Smarty is good for doing this kind of stuff (iterating over colors and styles), but it may be difficult for beginners.

Comment: +1 for the iteration approach, though I'd do the shading with a CSS class, and move the HTML outside of PHP strings.

Comment: Oh yes, keep the CSS outside. That can be easily changed of course. echo '<tr class="'.(($iter%2==0) ? $color1 : $color2).'">';

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

[Including CSS in .php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086785/including-css-in-php-file)

Answer (score 0):

Can I offer some advice on your code? Your approach mixes PHP and HTML in a way that makes it difficult for your development environment to parse your HTML, and you can achieve the same with less keystrokes! Consider this approach instead:

```
<?php while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $info['articlenr'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['stock'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Changes I've made:

- Removed the duplicate row
- Rendered everything in HTML mode, and opened PHP tags just for PHP code
- Switched the loop to the colon form, which is often thought to be clearer in templates. Do carry on using the brace approach, however, in large chunks of code (e.g. classes)
- Written PHP keywords in lower case
- Used `echo` rather than `print`

Combine this with Joke_Sense10's answer for a full solution.